# How to download(all) the source code from this site by using git?

Tags: git, tizen

I'm trying to get tizen's source code from https://review.tizen.org/git/ by using:

```
git clone git://review.tizen.org/git
```

But I get:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to fix this? the site is not specific in the address of git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see there are a bunch of different projects at that link. so you'll have to do something like the following:

```
git clone git://review.tizen.org/git/tools/sbs.git
```

Also I'll assume you have the correct access rights. Also you may want to look at `All-Projects.git` as it has some config and access information you need.

Comment: So do I need to download the projects one per one? there is access informations on`All-Projects.git` really. I can download it,but how do I use?

Comment: i don't know anything about the repos. just saw that repo looks like it has git access configuration. you can do something like create a file of all the repos then do `cat file | xargs -I'{}' git clone '{}'.git`

Comment: https://source.tizen.org/documentation/developer-guide/getting-started-guide/cloning-tizen-source

Answer (score 1):

[It](https://review.tizen.org/git/) seem to have multiple projects in the location so mention proper project repository when you make the clone.

> **For example**

Assuming you have proper credentials,

```
git clone https://review.tizen.org/git/All-Projects.git
                  OR
git clone git://review.tizen.org/git/All-Projects.git
```

this will clone `All-projects.git` to your local drive.

Comment: I replaced `https` by `git` protocol: `git clone git://review.tizen.org/All-Projects.git` download some files: `groups  project.config` but no source code. I have a login,maybe such credentials,how do I set it? I can't find a git's command-line-options to do it.

Comment: no credentials were probably set by your system administrator or someone who is authorized to do so. For git usually they add your ssh key as credential. For not being able to download only some files. Perhaps those are the only files in it. We wouldn't know about it. Perhaps you should ask the one who gave you about which projects you should clone.

Comment: yes I seems that direct http git are not available anymore ?


https://source.tizen.org/git/

    projects /
    404 - No projects found

Answer (score 1):

because tizen's all projects are huge, you'd better to pick up some interesting sub projects.

in example, I can clone ecore project like :

```
$ git clone git://review.tizen.org/framework/uifw/ecore.git
```

you can check the involving projects from https://review.tizen.org/git/

Answer (score 0):

This url will not requiere you to setup account and upload keys for gerrit

```
git clone https://git.tizen.org/cgit/Public-Projects.git
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Tizen documentation for more details. Essentially, it uses repo to download all the projects at once.

https://source.tizen.org/documentation/developer-guide/getting-started-guide/cloning-tizen-source